# Memory and/or GPU issues with electron

Tags: ubuntu, electron

I'm having trouble running [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/) on my Ubuntu 20 machine (from `uname -a`: `Linux hex 5.15.0-72-generic #79~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 22:12:07 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`).

Using the [quick start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) example I get:

```
git clone https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start
cd electron-quick-start
npm install

ls
index.html  LICENSE.md  main.js  node_modules  package.json  package-lock.json  preload.js  README.md  renderer.js

npm start

> electron-quick-start@1.0.0 start
> electron .

MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0
[1013783:1116/152512.482013:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(991)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=133
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0
[1013783:1116/152512.874930:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(991)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=133
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0
[1013783:1116/152513.252054:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(991)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=133
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0
[1013783:1116/152513.556500:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(991)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=133
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0
[1013783:1116/152513.859890:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(991)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=133
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0
[1013783:1116/152514.164676:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(991)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=133
[1013783:1116/152514.397741:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(991)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=133
[1013783:1116/152514.623582:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(991)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=133
[1013783:1116/152514.876075:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(991)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=133
[1013783:1116/152514.876105:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(448)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
/home/dario/Downloads/electron-quick-start/node_modules/electron/dist/electron exited with signal SIGTRAP
```

Adding the `--disable-gpu --no-sandbox` flags to the `electron` script in `package.json` doesn't help.

If I downgrade from the current electron v27 to v12.08 I still cannot run the application but the error changes to:

```
git clone https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start
cd electron-quick-start
# Checkout v12.08
git checkout 9ce0f18157ed06ef4370f9138270fb50a737e3ec
npm install
npm start

> electron-quick-start@1.0.0 start
> electron .

[1014120:1116/152740.443095:FATAL:memory_linux.cc(37)] Out of memory.
[1014159:1116/152740.849592:FATAL:memory_linux.cc(37)] Out of memory.
[1014172:1116/152741.201625:FATAL:memory_linux.cc(37)] Out of memory.
[1014185:1116/152741.454035:FATAL:memory_linux.cc(37)] Out of memory.
[1014188:1116/152741.688731:FATAL:memory_linux.cc(37)] Out of memory.
[1014191:1116/152741.921800:FATAL:memory_linux.cc(37)] Out of memory.
```

I have 16 GB of memory and from htop I don't think I'm running out of memory.

If now I replace `electron  .` with `electron --disable-gpu --no-sandbox .` I get the same errors but at least the application starts:

```
npm start

> electron-quick-start@1.0.0 start
> electron --disable-gpu --no-sandbox .

[1015761:1116/153729.638909:FATAL:memory_linux.cc(37)] Out of memory.
[1015791:1116/153729.970677:FATAL:memory_linux.cc(37)] Out of memory.
[1015794:1116/153730.227966:FATAL:memory_linux.cc(37)] Out of memory.
```

---

**UPDATE**: The latest version of electron that works for me is 26.3.0, i.e. the last version before the 27 series. No need for `--disable-gpu --no-sandbox`, it still gives some errors but it doesn't crash.

```
git checkout 20efb6474d7d741c0e4ab01d9eaf5cfe474a4b94

npm start

> electron-quick-start@1.0.0 start
> electron .

[1052403:1117/085607.145015:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(590)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.portal.Settings.Read: object_path= /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop: org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: Requested setting not found
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0
[1052403:1117/085607.586017:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(957)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=133
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0
[1052403:1117/085607.979760:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(957)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=133
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0
[1052403:1117/085608.389720:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(957)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=133
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0
[1052403:1117/085608.695295:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(957)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=133
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0
[1052403:1117/085609.005271:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(957)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=133
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0
[1052403:1117/085609.319020:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(957)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=133
```

Any idea how I can make a recent version of electron work?